# Why is my quiz not interacting with mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, session, web, process

I have been programming a web based quiz and I have stuck on this issue for a number of weeks now.

Basically I have used the var_dump function and I have found that infact my array is empty.

(C:\wamp64\www\MyProject\Quiz app\final.php:20:
array (size=0)
  empty).

The issue is that my quiz can pull the questions and choices using mysql database, however it cannot validate inputs. So this is why I can't also use the score variable. How can I fix this issue so that my quiz can validate answers with my database ?.

Your help will very greatly appreciated and will help a beginner programmer like myself. Thank you very much indeed.

```
#Question.php

    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php include "database.php"; 
    ?>


    <?php
    //Set question
    $number = (int) $_GET['n'];


        /*
     * Get Total Questions
    */
     $query="SELECT * FROM questions" ;
     //Get Results
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);



    /*
    * Get the Question
    */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions
    WHERE question_number = $number";

    //Get result
    $result = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);

    $question = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);


    /*
    * Get choices
    */
    $query2 = "SELECT * FROM choices
    WHERE question_number = $number";

    //Get result
    $choices = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);


    ?>



     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC'>
    <html> 
        <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
            <title>
                General Knowledge Quiz
            </title>
            <link href="css/other.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        </head>
        <body>
        <main>


    <div class="container" >
    <div class="current">Question <?php echo $question ['question_number'];?> of <?php echo $total; ?> </div>
    <p class="question">
     <?php echo $question ['text']; ?>
    </p>
    <form action="process.php" method="post"
      <ul class="choices"

    <?php while ($row = $choices->fetch_assoc()) : ?>
    <li><input name="choice" type="radio" value="<?php echo $row ['id'];?> " /><?php echo $row ['text']; ?></li>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sumbit"/>
          <input type="hidden" name= "number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />



     </main>
     </div>
        </body>
    </html>

    <?php endwhile?>
```

````
#Process.php

    <?php session_start(); ?>
    <?php include "database.php";?>
    <?php
    // check to see if score is set error_handler)
    if(!isset($_SESSION['score'] )) {
        $_SESSION ['score'] = 0;
    }   

    if($_POST) {
        $number = $_POST['number']; 
        $selected_choice = $_POST['choice'];
        $next = $number++;

        echo $number ;
        echo $selected_choice ; 
    }

        /*
     * Get Total Questions
    */
     $query="SELECT * FROM questions" ;
     //Get Results
    $results = mysqli_query ($conn,$query);
    $total = mysqli_num_rows($results);



        /*
        *   Get correct choice
        */
        $query = "SELECT * FROM choices
     WHERE question_number = $number AND is_correct=1";

    //Get result
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

    //Get Row
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 

    //Set Correct choice
    $correct_choice = $row['id'];


    //Compare
    if ($correct_choice == $selected_choice) {
        //Answer is correct
    $_SESSION['score']++;}



    //Check if it is the last question
    if($number == $total){
        header("Location: final.php") ;
        exit();
        }  
        else { 
          header("Location: question.php?n=".$next);

        }
        ```
````

Comment: your while loop is incorrectly looping around the closing tags of `main`,`div`,`body` and `html`

Comment: Also, input elements are not valid direct children of `ul` elements

Comment: You have no closing `form` tag and the opening form tag is incorrect as there is no closing `>`. The same is true of the `ul` tag - it lacks the closing `>`

Comment: You are incorrectly closing tags - they need to be closed in reverse order of being opened so the `<main><div>... ` should finish `...</div></main>`

Comment: you have no closing `form` tag nor closing `ul` tag

Comment: and your SQL is vulnerable to SQL injection - use `prepared statements` instead of embedding user supplied data directly in the sql

Comment: Thank you so much for your help – RamRaider !

Comment: Rather than two separate queries you can and should `join` the tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having seen the database schema there is a certain amount of guesswork here based upon what I deduce from the above but I hope it might help point the way towards the solution. It looks like the 3 queries used initially can be replaced with a single query that joins the two tables and also does a sub-query to find the total record count. A similar combined query can be done I think in `process.php`

**The question.... Question.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if( !isset( $_SESSION['score'] ) )$_SESSION['score']=0;
    $number = isset( $_GET['n'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['n'] ) ? intval( $_GET['n'] ) : 1;


    include "database.php"; 



    $sql="select
            ( select count(*) from `questions` ) as `total`,
            q.`question_number` as `qid`, 
            q.`text` as `question`, 
            c.`id` as `aid`, 
            c.`text` as `answer` 
        from `questions` q
            join `choices` c on c.`question_number`=q.`question_number`
        where q.`question_number` = ?";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );

    if( $stmt ){
        $stmt->bind_param('i',$number);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $total, $qid, $question, $aid, $answer );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC'>
<html> 
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>General Knowledge Quiz</title>
        <link href="css/other.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div class="container" >

                <div class="current">Question <?php printf('%d of %d',$qid,$total); ?></div>
                <p class="question"><?php echo $question; ?></p>

                <form action="process.php" method="post">
                    <ul class="choices">
                    <?php
                        if( $stmt ){
                            while( $rs=$stmt->fetch() ){
                                printf('
                                    <li>
                                        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="%d" />%s
                                    </li>',
                                    $aid,
                                    $answer
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </ul>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sumbit" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="number" value="<?php echo $number; ?>" />
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

**And to process the request: process.php**

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if( isset( $_POST['number'], $_POST['choice'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['number'] ) ){

            session_start();
            include "database.php";

            if( !isset( $_SESSION['score'] ) ) $_SESSION['score'] = 0;
            $choice=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'choice', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );
            $number=filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'number', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT );


            $sql='select 
                ( select count(*) from questions ) as `total`,
                `id`
                from `choices`
                where `question_number`=? and is_correct=1;';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            if( $stmt ){
                $stmt->bind_param('i',$number);
                $res=$stmt->execute();
                if( $res ){
                    $stmt->store_result();
                    $stmt->bind_result($total,$id);

                    $stmt->fetch();
                    if( $id==$choice )$_SESSION['score']++;
                    $stmt->free_result();
                    $stmt->close();


                    if( $number==$total )exit( header('Location: final.php') );
                    else exit( header( sprintf('Location: question.php?n=%s',( $number + 1 ) ) ) );
                }
            }
        }
        exit();
    }
    http_response_code(400);
?>
```

It should be noted that none of this has been tested so there may well be syntax errors

Comment: Wow, thank you so incredibly much !! You have helped me fix my problem which has taken so long to solve. Kudos to you !

Comment: One small question. How do I make it print the question number it is on ? It thinks it is on question 0 out of 0 ?

Comment: the piece `<?php printf('%d of %d',$qid,$total); ?>` should print that.. check the PHP error log to see if there are any errors relating to this

Comment: I don't think I got any errors in the php error log for this. Do you think the problem could be the %d argument? Should i be using something else ? I'm not sure

Comment: Another problem I have found is that the actual question is not being printed . I am unsure how to solve this.